# Does it make sense to check-in Visual Studio Code typings folder with dts?

Tags: tsd, visual-studio-code

Working with Visual Studio Code. It suggested to import types definition and downloaded them into /typings folder.

Do I need to check this folder in or it can be restored somehow?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that checking in the tsd.json helps with setting up new developers or even reinstalling typings if you need to clone the repo somewhere as tsd wont know what to reinstall if you do not.

1. `tsd init` (this creates the tsd.json file)
2. `tsd install node --save` (this will create the typings folder if there isn't one and add the node typing to the tsd.json)
3. check in the tsd.json file and gitignore the typings folder(tsd uses the json to recreate your typings folder)
4. tell co-workers to `tsd install` from root to get that typing goodness!

`source: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd#quick-start`

Answer (score 0):

If the type definition files (.d.ts) are internal and not available in any central dts repository such as typings (which is replacing tsd), then it makes sense to add them to source control.

If not, the rule is that **any generated or retrievable file should not be added to source control**.
Type definition files (.d.ts) can be retrieved with `typings` tool for example.

A common practice if you use NPM to manage dependencies and build/delivery pipeline is to have a `package.json` file where you add the dependencies and some scripts. Consider the following `package.json`:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "iberodev",
  "description": "iberodev sample",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "devDependencies": {
    "live-server": "^0.9.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.6.0",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.28",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "typings install dt~jquery dt~angular dt~angular-animate dt~angular-material --global --save"
  }
}
```

Above there is a dependency (among others) on `typings`. There is also a postinstall script with the command `typings install dt~jquery dt~angular dt~angular-animate dt~angular-material --global --save`

When a developer clones the repository and then executes the command `npm install` all the specified dependencies will be downloaded and after that the typings command to download type definition files under a local folder `typings/` will be executed, therefore it's unnecessary to add those files to source control and your `.gitignore` should contain at least these lines:

```
**/typings/**
typings.json
```